# "Error. An error occurred while processing your request" when upload project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, shopify-app

I just built my first shopify app. It looks to run well when working on localhost using ngrok. But when I upload my application to hosting, I get an error message when trying to install the application via shopify.
**"Error. An error occurred while processing your request."**
I've done all the possible steps in my head, but I have not been able to cope. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Try enabling the detailed logging through webconfig, that should show you what's wrong. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx

Comment: okey, thank you.. solved,,